# Show, that $B:=\{u\in C([0,h],\mathbb R^n):\|u\|<\infty\}$ with $\|u\|=\sup\limits_{t\in (0,h]} \frac{|u(t)|}{t}$ is a Banach space.

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Let $B:=\{u\in C([0,h],\mathbb R^n):\|u\|<\infty\}$ with $\|u\|=\sup\limits_{t\in (0,h]} \frac{|u(t)|}{t}$.
Show, that $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banachspace.
To show, that $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space, i have to show, that a Cauchy-sequence converges in $B$. Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: What have you tried? What precise issues in the proof are you facing?

Comment: Let $f_n$ be a Cauchy-Sequence in B. So we have $\|f_n-f_m\|=\sup\limits_{t\in(0,h]} \frac{|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|}{t}<\epsilon$. Now I dont know, how I can show that this sequence converges in $B$:

Comment: @andy Ok, so it easily follows that for every specific $t$, $(f_n(t))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and so converges to some limit $f(t)$. There you have your limit function. Of course you still have to prove that $f$ belongs to the space and that $f_n\to f$.

Comment: I have to show, that $f$ is continuous and $\|f\|<\infty$, right?